# What's making holes in the trunk/stem of my succulent?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, succulents

Something is making holes in the stem/trunk of my succulent, and is now making holes in an offshoot. When I stick my fingers in the dark hole, it feels gritty.

I don't see any insects in the hole or on the plant. I don't want to lose the succulent, which has leaves like paddles. I've had it a long time. I take it in during the winter and put it outside in the spring in the sun. I live in Atlanta, GA. I haven't noticed any problems with the succulent beside it.

Do you know what the holes might be and how I can treat the plant? It is otherwise very healthy. Also, do you know the name of this succulent? Can't find it online.

Comment: am I missing the picture?

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.